# Kernel composed with inverse of random variable is a kernel?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, expected-value

##### Set Up

- $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ probability space
- $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ measurable space
- $Y:\Omega\to\mathsf{Y}$ random variable with distribution $P_Y = \mathbb{P} \circ Y^{-1}$
- $k:\Omega\times \mathcal{F}\to[0, 1]$ be a markov kernel (and a regular conditional probability)

##### Question

> Can I construct another Markov Kernel $\tilde{k}:\mathsf{Y}\times\mathcal{F}\to[0, 1]$ such that this holds?
> $$
> \int_{Y^{-1}(\mathsf{B})} k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) \,d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathsf{B}} \tilde{k}(y, \mathsf{A}) \, d P_Y(y) \qquad \qquad \forall \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{F} \text{ and } \forall \mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{Y}
> $$

##### Attempted Solution

Since the measure we are integrating changes, my guess was to attempt to use the Change of Variables formula. We know $P_Y(\mathsf{B}) = \mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(\mathsf{B}))$ for $\mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{Y}$. Hence I thought of writing $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}) = \mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(Y(\mathsf{A})))$ and then
$$
\int_{Y^{-1}(\mathsf{B})} k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) \, d\mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(Y(\omega))) = \int_{\mathsf{B}} k(\cdot, \mathsf{A}) \circ Y^{-1}(y) dP_Y(y)
$$
This seems to almost work but then what in the hell is $k(\cdot, \mathsf{A}) \circ Y^{-1}$ and is it even a kernel? What's his source and target measurable spaces? I am very confused.

Comment: It is not true that $A = Y^{-1}(Y(A))$. After unravelling definitions, you are asking for a kernel $\tilde{k}$ such that for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$, $\tilde{k}(Y(\cdot), A) = E(k(\cdot, A) \mid Y)$.

Comment: @Mason Thank you. How did you get to that definition of the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Such a kernel exists if the spaces involved are well-behaved enough to admit [regular conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability). For example, it works if $\Omega$ and $Y$ are [Polish spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) with $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, respectively, the Borel $\sigma$-algebras. To make the notation easier to parse, I write $f$ for the random variable.
In that case, there exists a kernel $\tau:Y\times\mathcal{F}\to [0,1]$ such that for every $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $B\in\mathcal{Y}$, one has
$$\mathbb{P}\big(A\cap f^{-1}(B)\big)=\int_B\tau(y,A)~\mathrm dP_Y.$$
Write $\mathbb{P}^B$ for the measure defined by the left side. Now,
$$\int_{f^{-1}(B)}k(\omega,A)~\mathrm d\mathbb{P}=\int k(\omega,A)~\mathrm d\mathbb{P}^B=\int_B\int k(\omega,A)~\mathrm d\tau(y,\cdot)~\mathrm dP_Y.$$ So the kernel $\bar{k}$ given by $$\bar{k}(y,A)=\int k(\omega,A)~\mathrm d\tau(y,\cdot)$$ works.